# How to Include child properties in EF Core with TPH

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to build an application using .net Core and EF Core (2.0) and stumbled into a use case where I have a hierarchy, which is mapped using TPH (table per hierarchy) and need to query the parent class but eagerly include child classes relations (an SQL left join).

Simplifying things I have a structure similar to:

```
public class Person
{
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public StudentType Type { get; set; }
}
```

I created a controller for the Person type, which returns persons and students, but all StudentType's are null because I did not Include() them. How can I include it if my DbSet is of type Person?

```
return this.Context.Person.Include(???).ToList();
```

Comment: Shortly - wait for v2.1

Comment: Searched everywhere and did not see it. Thanks!